# Getting JSON value from cURL in Linux Bash

Tags: json, linux, bash, curl

I want to `GET` some json data from a server. I do this using:

```
UPDATE=$(curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" --cookie "${COOKIE_NAME}" "${1}/update/${DEVICE_NAME}");
```

Before this, the server is authenticated. The `${1}` is the server domain, `${DEVICE_NAME}` is the name of the device requesting the update.

This returns a JSON as follows:

> [{"_id":"54ff35887d8ef574029b9166","user":"54fe4313883bcec2c0ac0d64","__v":0,"created":"2015-03-10T18:18:48.023Z","status":"available","pbo_udid":"lemaker","installation_script":"","description":"Prints
>   hello world to
>   console","package_name":"helloworld_1.0-1.deb","name":"Hello World
>   V1"}]

I want to now do 2 things:

1. Make sure data is returned (if no update is available, the server returns `[]`
2. Extract data, for instance `package_name`

How do I do these in Linux bash script?

Comment: You will likely need to pass the JSON value to a CLI for a script processor that can deserialize the JSON string and extract the data you are looking for. (i.e. something like PERL, PHP, etc.). Of course, at that point, I would probably just write the entire logic to retrieve and extract the data in that scripting language. Outside of that, you are likely looking at putting together some awkward combination of `sed`, `awk`, etc. to, in essence, build a deserializer.

Comment: There are some really great tools for parsing JSON from bash; `jq` is one of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there's no nested array:

```
cat <<EOF | json_reformat | \
    sed -rne '/:/s@^\s+"(\w+)":\s+"([^"]+)",?@json_\1="\2"@gp'
[{"_id":"54ff35887d8ef574029b9166","user":"54fe4313883bcec2c0ac0d64","__v":0,"created":"2015-03-10T18:18:48.023Z","status":"available","pbo_udid":"lemaker","installation_script":"","description":"Prints hello world to console","package_name":"helloworld_1.0-1.deb","name":"Hello World V1"}]
EOF
```

returns

```
json__id="54ff35887d8ef574029b9166"
json_user="54fe4313883bcec2c0ac0d64"
json_created="2015-03-10T18:18:48.023Z"
json_status="available"
json_pbo_udid="lemaker"
json_description="Prints hello world to console"
json_package_name="helloworld_1.0-1.deb"
json_name="Hello World V1"
```

You need `json_reformat` for this to work.

**EDIT** : without `json_reformat`:

```
cat <<EOF | \
    sed -re 's@(\[|\]|\{|\})@@g' -e 's/,/\n/g' | \
    sed -re 's@"(\w+)":\s*"?([^"]*)"?@json_\1="\2"@g'
[{"_id":"54ff35887d8ef574029b9166","user":"54fe4313883bcec2c0ac0d64","__v":0,"created":"2015-03-10T18:18:48.023Z","status":"available","pbo_udid":"lemaker","installation_script":"","description":"Prints hello world to console","package_name":"helloworld_1.0-1.deb","name":"Hello World V1"}]
EOF
```

It returns (note the version number that is reformatted anyway):

```
json__id="54ff35887d8ef574029b9166"
json_user="54fe4313883bcec2c0ac0d64"
json___v="0"
json_created="2015-03-10T18:18:48.023Z"
json_status="available"
json_pbo_udid="lemaker"
json_installation_script=""
json_description="Prints hello world to console"
json_package_name="helloworld_1.0-1.deb"
json_name="Hello World V1"
```

You can now try parsing this text using `eval` or source it from stdin.

Comment: Thanks. Any way to use it without downloading `json_format`?? I don't want to install other files

Comment: It might be possible to enhance the `sed` script. What I like in `json_reformat` is it spares you the burden of verifying and sanitizing the received data.

Comment: See my edited response, without  `json_reformat`.

Comment: Pipe content retrieved from a web page into `eval`? Are you _trying_ to get your system rooted?

Comment: @charles-duffy Not mine, no... More seriously, this is a hint of course. Using the evil `eval` is certainly not the only option. There are few of them however as the OP wishes no supplemental package.

Comment: Quite true; one could redirect results so processed into a loop using `printf -v` to set contents into variables, or (safer) into as associative array, if using bash 4, but the sensitive work (of the actual parsing) remains something to which bash is unsuited without `json_reformat` or other external tools (and without auditing `json_reformat`, I'm not sure about the eval-safety of its output; using double-quotes is a smell on that count).

Answer (score 11):

Much more easily and reliably done using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) or [jsawk](https://github.com/micha/jsawk):

```
content=$(curl ...)
package_name=$(jq -r '.package_name' <<<"$content")
```

Comment: saved my day!! exactly what I was looking for! :D